# error: unknown filesystem

Tags: grubrescue

Today I installed Ubuntu 15.10 and everything was fine until I switched back to Windows to free a hard drive partition which wasn't allocated to any OS.

When I deleted it and rebooted my system I realised the Ubuntu was installed on that partition and now I am getting grub rescue error.

I tried using my bootable flashdrive to install Ubuntu once more, but all I am getting is the same error and it wouldn't recognize my Windows 7 DVD as well. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution, but you will need an Ubuntu Live USB.

- Boot with the live USB;
- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>);
- Run `sudo gparted`;
- In GParted, click in the "GParted" tab, devices, and choose your USB stick (probably sdb);
- I suppose your flash drive has only one partition. Right-click this partition, click "Resize" and shrink it about 500 MB. This will leave you with half a GB of unallocated space;
- Right-click the new unallocated space and then click new. Create a new partition formatted as ext2!!! in your flash drive (formatting it as ext2 is VERY important);
- Close GParted. Open a new terminal window and run `sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt` (again, I suppose your flash drive is sdb);
- Run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda --root-directory=/mnt`;
- Reboot your computer. You will be dropped in the GRUB rescue prompt again. Run the following commands:

  ```
  insmod ext2
  set prefix=(hd1,msdos2)/boot/grub
  insmod normal
  insmod ntfs
  insmod chain
  set root=(hd0,msdos1)
  ```

I suppose Windows is in the first partition, change `msdos1` to suit your case;

```
chainloader +1
boot
```

And Windows should boot. My mission ends here. Now you'll have to repair Windows's bootloader. One hint: look for "EasyBCD" on Google.

Comment: Thanks, but I already got it fixed by pressing f12. Anyway your answer is appreciated. :)